# Audio and 3G data via UART in GSM module using AT commands

Tags: gsm, at-command, 3g, orange-pi

I have got a question. I want to buy a GSM/GPS/3G module for minicomputer like Orange Pi Zero Plus 2, so it can't be something like [Raspberry Pi GSM Hat](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Waveshare-4G-HAT-Raspberry-SIM7600E-H/dp/B07F1NSGQ8). I have found really [good module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3G-Cellular-Breakout-115200Bps-Baud-SIM5320E-3G-GSM-GPRS-GPS-Expansion-Board-Mini-3G-WCDMA-GPS/32849846890.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.1.2b074f59Dr26S3&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_10065_10068_318_319_10696_450_10084_10083_10618_452_535_534_10304_533_10307_10820_532_10301_10821_5727311_204_10843_5727211_10059_10884_10887_100031_320_10103_448_449,searchweb201603_60,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=664e0fef-4e46-4f11-8d1f-82e71dbce0a6-0&algo_pvid=664e0fef-4e46-4f11-8d1f-82e71dbce0a6&transAbTest=ae803_5&priceBeautifyAB=0), but I am not sure about some things. Maybe you can help me.

First. Internet connection. SIM5320 is 3G module, so maximum speed of Internet connection will be 3.6Mb. As you can see in the picture below this module has got only UART interface. Will I be able to use the maximum 3G speed via the UART interface?

Second. Audio. This module doesn't have audio input or output. So can I send and receive audio using UART interface and AT commands?

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look [datasheet of the SIM5320 module](https://www.tinyosshop.com/datasheet/SIM5320_Hardware+Design_V1.07.pdf) it says the following about the UART interface:

[image]

So it is probably not the bottle neck, if terminal can use the highest bit rates.

Such modems usually have separate audio-output and mic-input pins. That can be used for audio phone calls with ATD and ATA AT-command. SIM5320 seems to have such pins, but the board seems to not have such connector.

UART can be used for Internet access for uploading/downloading binary audio stream over IP. But that would require quite much software for terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I have some experience using 3g modules. I have always managed to recieve good speeds through the UART interface.

As for audio, you can definitely start calls through AT commands, but I don't think you can stream audio over UART.

Maybe consider something like [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2687)?